Where does the third solution come from?
There's a well known trick with polynomials. If we have
\begin{align*}
&&(x-r_1)(x-r_2) &= 0 \\
&& x^2 -(r_1+r_2)x + r_1r_2 &=0 \tag{*}\label{*} \\
&\text{so}& x^2 &= (r_1+r_2)x - r_1r _2 \tag{**}\label{**}
\end{align*}
Now, we can multiply both sides of $\ref{*}$ by $x$ to get which adds a solution $x=0$ to our original polynomial.
\begin{align*}
&& x^3 - (r_1 + r_2)x^2 + r_1 r_2 x &= 0 \\
&\text{and by} \, \ref{**} & x^3 - (r_1 + r_2)\left((r_1+r_2)x - r_1r _2\right) + r_1 r_2 x &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
But after the substitution, $x=0$ is no longer a solution. instead $x=-(r_1 + r_2)$ is the third solution.
$$(x - r_1)(x-r_2)\left(x + (r_1 + r_2)\right) = 0$$
So my question is why does the solution set change? And why is the third solution the one that it is. I get that $$\left(1 - \frac{r_1 + r_2}{x}\right)(x^3 - (r_1+r_2)x^2 + r_1 r_2 x = (x - r_1)(x-r_2)\left(x + (r_1 + r_2)\right)$$
but I haven't done that multiplication. I get that the constant term of $$(x - r_1)(x-r_2)\left(x + (r_1 + r_2)\right)$$
is $(r_1 + r_2)r_1 r_2$ and since $r_1$ and $r_2$ remain solutions, the only possibility for the third one is $-(r_1 + r_2)$. I have verified all of this, but it doesn't explain satisfactorily where that solution came from and why it is what it is.

Multiplying by $x$ to add the solution $x=0$ is the same as multiplying by $0$. You can generate absurdities when you accidentally do this.

@EricSnyder No, multiplying a polynomial by $x$ is not the same that multiplying by $0$.

The problem is that when you substitute $x^2$ by $(r_1+r_2)x-r_1r_2$ you are assuming that $x=r_1$ or $x=r_2$. You can set $x=0$ after that.

Let $P(x)=x^2-bx-c$ be the polynomial of interest. Then the "substitution" obtained by solving for $x^2=bx+c$ amounts to taking $xP(x)=x^3-bx^2-cx$ and adding $bP(x)$ to cancel off the quadratic term. Hence the new polynomial is $(x+b)P(x)$, which naturally has $x=-b$ as an additional root. Since $b=r_1+r_2$, the claim follows.
